# Eclipse RCP app fails to start

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP app running on Java 6.  When I try to run the product configuration from within Eclipse, it silently terminates almost immediately.  No error is reported in the console.  I've tried setting breakpoints in the IApplication and in the Activator, and neither are reached.

I know I don't have much specific information here, but can anyone give me any pointers on  where I might start looking to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the logs in runtime/.metadata folder?,
 Also make sure to validate all plugins in the runtime. Having them as a dependency doesn't necessarily mean they are added to the runtime. This is probably the biggest gotcha when launching an rcp app.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to locate the runtime/.metadata folder, but [this very helpful post](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.rhtml) directed me to add -consoleLog and -noExit to my runtime arguments, which dumped the errors to the console.  Configuration problems.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem after migrating my RCP app from 3.7 to 4.2.   The solution for me was to delete to runtime-product.product directory and re-run.